# Update only date in datetime object in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a variable1

```
 DateTime obj = DateTime.Now; // 08/13/2018 03:42pm

 DateTime responseDate = result.respDate; // 08/06/2018 03:40pm
```

I want to replace date part in obj variable with responseDate variable.
like i want to get

08/13/2018 03:40pm.

Comment: Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6(v=vs.110).aspx to create the date you want, by reading the appropriate parts from the dates that you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime obejcts have a property Date, which gives you just the date portion as a DateTime.  It also has a TimeOfDay property, which is a TimeSpan, so:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime responseDate = result.respDate;
TimeSpan responseTime = responseDate.TimeOfDay;
DateTime response = today + responseTime;
```

[There is also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) a `DateTime.Today` property too, which does the same thing as the first line.

Answer (score 4):

Get the today's date with [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today)

```
DateTime obj = DateTime.Today;
```

Get the time part of the `result.respDate` with [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday)

```
TimeSpan responseTime = result.respDate.TimeOfDay;
```

Add this time part to your `obj` with [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add)

```
DateTime responseDate = obj.Add(responseTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining the answers to a one-liner:

```
DateTime combinedDate = DateTime.Today.Add(result.respDate.TimeOfDay);
```